# Wrong results from custom reference system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I'm trying to define a custom CRS in QGIS using PROJ4 format.
Here's the string I used:

`+proj=tmerc +ellps=GRS80 +datum = ETRS89 +lon_0 =11.86 +lat_0 = 0 +x_0 =40000 +y_0=-6013000 +units=m +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +to_meter +nodefs`

here's the original geodetic infos:

[image]

WGS84 coordinates lat = 54.95 lon = 11.86 should give me something like x = 39763 y = 79272 instead I get y = 14296754 x = 757997.

Does anybody know what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Please be kind with this newbie

Comment: `ETRS89` is not a valid entry for `+datum`. You may run `proj -ld` to get the allowed values. And try to avoid blanks before and after the `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=11.86667 +k=1 +x_0=40000 +y_0=-6013000 +ellps=GRS80  +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```